# Datamapper transaction doesn't rollback

Tags: ruby, transactions, datamapper, rollback

I have such code:

```
Vhost.transaction do
  domains.each  do |domain| 
    unless domain.save
      errors << domain.errors
    end
  end
  unless vhost.save
    errors << vhost.errors
  end
end
```

I expect a rollback if any domain.save or vhost.save fails. But there is no rollback. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had success with this pattern:

```
DataMapper::Model.raise_on_save_failure = true

MyModel.transaction do
  begin
    # do stuff
  rescue DataMapper::SaveFailureError
    t.rollback
  end
end
```

*Edit*

Ok so you want to keep record of all errors before rolling back, then try something like this:

```
Vhost.transaction do |t|
  new_errors = []

  domains.each  do |domain| 
    unless domain.save
      new_errors << domain.errors
    end
  end

  unless vhost.save
    new_errors << vhost.errors
  end

  errors += new_errors
  t.rollback if new_errors.any?
end
```

Comment: Isn't that practically the same thing? But glad i could help.